# Change physical camera lens shift axis through script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an HDRP camera that contain physical properties such as Lens, Aperture etc. There is a property for Shift (X, Y) under Lens. How do I change the value of X for this property through script?

```
using UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition;

    void Update () {

        HDAdditionalCameraData cameraData = GetComponent<HDAdditionalCameraData>();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: this isnt specific to the HD camera, did you even google this, a short google came back with links including code..

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-lensShift.html ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the actual `Camera` component, not the `HDAdditionalCameraData`, this is a sample MonoBehaviour that does what you're looking for, use the public method `SetLensShift(Vector2)`. It's up to you to decide when to call that.

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Core
{
    public class LensShiftSetter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Camera _camera;
        
        private void Start()
        {
            _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        }

        public void SetLensShift(Vector2 value)
        {
            _camera.lensShift = value;
        }
    }
}
```